# Flask-SqlAlchemy RuntimeError: No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, quart

I try to implement Flask-SqlAlchemy in a Quart application it MVC structure. So I want every Model Have its file and functions.

This is my files:
**app.py**

```
__package__ = 'nini'

from .setups import create_app
from .db import db

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()
    db.init_app(app)

    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', debug=True)
```

**db.py**

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

**tests.py** Model file

```
from nini.db import db
import datetime


class Test(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = db.Column(db.VARCHAR)
    created = db.Column(db.DATETIME, default=datetime.datetime.now())
    pass

    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Test %r>' % self.id, self.created

    @classmethod
    async def create_new(cls, **kw):
        obj = cls(**kw)
        db.session.add(obj)
        db.session.commit()
        pass
```

**test.py**

```
import logging

from quart import jsonify, app, current_app
from quart_openapi import PintBlueprint
from datetime import datetime

from nini.models import tests
from nini.db import db

results = PintBlueprint('test', __name__)


@results.route('/test/test')
async def get_tests():
    logging.error("HELLO")
    t = await tests.Test.create_new(text="TT")
    logging.error("Done")
    return jsonify(t), 200
```

When I run `/test/test` path it works fine until `db.session.add(obj)1 line.
Then I get this error:

> RuntimeError: No application found. Either work inside a view function
> or push an application context. See
> http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/contexts/.
> INFO:quart.serving:127.0.0.1:50537 GET /test/test 1.1 500 - 21836

I tried adding this code at `app.py`:

```
db.init_app(app) ### This line was already in my code
with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
```

Also like this:

```
db.init_app(app) ### This line was already in my code
app.app_context().push():
db.create_all()
```

I also tried running `create_new` at `tasts.py` with context.
Tried implementing the `create_all` and test model inside `db.py`

Basically after `db.init_app(app)` whenever I use `db` I get the error.

Would love for some help.

Comment: Are you also using the Quart Flask-Patch system, https://pgjones.gitlab.io/quart/how_to_guides/flask_extensions.html ?

Comment: I am an Idiot. 
Thank you.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue and adding flask patch to the test and conftest.py don't solve it. The workaround that I found is to put `db.app = app`  right after `db.init_app(app)`